# Что нужно делать для статического поддомена динамического сайта для лучшей SEO?

Tags: javascript, css, seo, static, google-search-console

Есть сайт example.com
В него подключаются css и js файлы из static.example.com
Нужно ли добавить example.com в Search Console Google, или для таких случаев есть какие-либо настройки?
Дело в том что при сканировании страниц сайта гуглботом он его не правильно видит из-за того, что  стили подключаются из поддомена.
Может ктолибо сталкивался с такой проблемой? В гугл и на хабре не нашел решение, так как не знаю по какому запросу можно будет найти.

Answer (score 1):

Если example.com является главной страницей вашего сайта, т.е. это index, то его рекомендуют добавлять в Search Console Google. Для подключения стилей укажите прямой линк, например `<link rel=stylesheet href=style.css />`. **[Инфо Гугл](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=ru)**.
**Ваши комментарии**: "*1) Ведь у этих поддоменов нет html файлов. Разве это будет правильно добавлять их если они состоят только из css и js файлов*". У поддоменов могут быть файлы html, например главная страница поддомена: de.main.html 
"*2)Насчет этого полностью не согласен с вами. Гугл заявил что mobile-friendly серьезно влияет на ранжирование сайта. Следственно стили важны для SEO*". Для поисковой оптимизации важны не стили, а возможность для пользователей просматривать ваш сайт на мобильных устройствах.

Comment: Если стили не подгружаются, то сайт становится не "mobile-friendly". Следственно стили важны. Спорить не к чему. Об этом есть статьи. можете почитать. да и без статей можно придти к этому выводу. КЭП, насчет link я знаю. но выяснилось что все дело в роботс.тхт. Я исправил его в поддоменах и все заработало. А без этого страницы считались не  "mobile-friendly"

Answer (score 0):

1. Гугл рекомендует добавлять поддомены которые вы хотели бы отслеживать.
2. Стили и их источник никак не должны влиять на индексацию.

Comment: 1) Ведь у этих поддоменов нет html файлов. Разве это будет правильно добавлять их если они состоят только из css и js файлов
2)Насчет этого полностью не согласен с вами. Гугл заявил что mobile-friendly серьезно влияет на ранжирование сайта. Следственно стили важны для SEO

Comment: @HasanaghaAliyev 1. Не имеет значения как у вас организована серверная часть. html файлов может вообще не быть. 2. Путаете ранжирование и индексацию. Возможно стили могут повлиять на индексацию если вы весь текст сделаете белым цветом (т.е. невидимым), но это уже другая тема которая называется манипулирование поисковыми алгоритмами.

Comment: нет я не путаю..стили влияют именно на ранжирование..например, если кнопки расположены слишком близко или размер элемента превышает разммер экрана гаджета то сайт становится не mobile-friendly и по этой причине в ранжировании опускается ниже чем те сайты в которых нет этой проблемы(конечноже на ранжирование влияют и другие факторы, и это лишь один из них)

Answer (score 0):

Добавил поддомену robots.txt и в нем указал Allow: *.css. После этого сайт начал корректно отображаться в таких сервисах как "Просмотреть как Googlebot".